# how to read two or more digit inputs from a BARCODE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website and I want to read the input from the bar code.

While I am getting the input from bar code keyboard input should not be considered as a input since when I am trying to get the integer inputs key board is giving inputs. 
below is the code which I tried with:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.altKey & (e.which > 47 && e.which < 58)) {
        var value = "";
        value += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        window.location = "../../patient_overview_c/view/" + value;
    }
});
```

I want to get the input while I am pressing the alt key. I have done this for only one digit vale. I want to go for two or more digits.

Comment: what is your problem? what do you mean "Alt key", are you reading the barcode with a barcode reader while you are interfering with another keyboard pressing the alt-key?

Answer (score 0):

You are having one ampersand instead of two, on your second line. The `e.altKey` returns a bool.

Change

```
 if (e.altKey & (e.which > 47 && e.which < 58)) {
               ^
```

into

```
 if (e.altKey && (e.which > 47 && e.which < 58)) {
               ^
```